# how to add default array to given array list?

Tags: php

From the query, I get name year and month name and its rate. From the query some year have only 4 months. So how can I add other missing months with default rate 0.0 to following array?

```
$data = array();
foreach($result as $key => $val){
    $data[$val['name']][$val['year']][date('F', strtotime("2000-".$val['month']."-01"))]= $val['rate'];
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample data of `$result`

Comment: @executable here is his sample data ^^ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004483/how-to-create-an-multidimensonal-array-based-on-the-common-field-name

Comment: This question would be a lot simpler if you would just provide sample `input` and sample `output`. E.g. https://bpaste.net/raw/0de604fbd6ea

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array();
foreach($result as $key => $val){
    if(!isset($data[$val['name']][$val['year']])) {
        //Initialize year array
        $data[$val['name']][$val['year']] = array(
        "January" => "0.0","February" => "0.0","March" => "0.0","April" => "0.0","May" => "0.0","June" => "0.0","July" => "0.0","August" => "0.0","September" => "0.0","October" => "0.0","November" => "0.0","December" => "0.0"
        ); 
    }
    $data[$val['name']][$val['year']][date('F', strtotime("2000-".$val['month']."-01"))]= $val['rate'];
}
```

Initialize year array as given in above code